# Definition of generalized cohomology with coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cofibrations

I am trying to understand the definition of generalized cohomology with coefficients. Suppose we have a generalized cohomology $E$. Let $p$ be a prime number. Then there is the Moore spectrum $M(\mathbb{F}_p)$, which comes from a cofiber sequence $\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S} \to M(\mathbb{F}_p)$, and $E_{\mathbb{F}_p} := E \wedge M(\mathbb{F}_p)$, where $E_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ should be the cohomology theory $E$ with coefficient $\mathbb{F}_p$. I cannot find what exactly the cofiber sequence $\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S} \to M(\mathbb{F}_p)$ looks like and what it has to do with the definition of $E_{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Does anybody know what the cofiber map is?

Comment: It's multiplication by $p$.

Comment: What exactly is this map? Is every element in $S^n$ multiplied by $p$?

Comment: On the level of topological spaces, the map is a degree $p$ map. So on $S^1$, you can take it to be the $p$th power map, and on $S^n$ it's the appropriate suspension of the $p$th power map.

Comment: Alternatively, see Hatcher, Example 2.40, for instance, for the Moore space and then apply the suspension spectrum construction.

Comment: Thank you. Can this be any degree $p$ map? And do you know a source for the proof of the existence of such a cofiber map? (To cite it in my work)

Comment: What's wrong with Hatcher as a reference?